# Network problem after update

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, netplan

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a PC with 4 network interfaces: enp1s0, enp2s0, enp3s0 & enp4s0. I'm using enp1s0 (outgoing interface, configured by the cable modem using DHCP) and enp4s0 (static IP, local network).

Everything was working fine until earlier today when I did 'apt upgrade; reboot'. The machine came up but 'ifconfig' shows enp2s0 and enp3s0 only, not 1 & 4. I can configure 1 & 4 manually using 'ifconfig' on the command line and then they start working. The 'Network' applet in 'Settings' shows only enp2s0 & enp3s0 and says cable unplugged (correct).

What happened to enp1s0 and enp4s0 and how can I bring them back?

This is in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.86.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.86.0
broadcast 192.168.86.255

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```

Output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated in Ubuntu 22.04 and not supported by default.  Is there a reason you're using this instead of netplan?

Comment: I didn't know this. This machine has been running Ubuntu since 14.04 so that's how it was set up. It worked just fine until this weekend. Is there a procedure on how to migrate off /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: And since this machine is a server, I don't want NetworkManager, just netplan, right?

Comment: Yes, netplan. See example templates at /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples. Let us know if you need further guidance.

Comment: So I have a netplan yaml config that works but only if the renderer is networkd, it stops working if the renderer is NetworkManager. This machine is a server although it has X installed but not normally running. Is it okay to just disable NetworkManager and go with networkd?